# UIScrollView doesn't work when view starts but does work after rotation

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

I have a `UIScrollView` to display a longer listing of textviews, fields and images. In the `viewDidAppear` I set the contentSize appropriately and I also add this code to `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation` so that the `UIScrollView` contentSize resizes based on the orientation.

Problem is that when the view first appears the `UIScrollView` doesn't respond (I can't scroll) but after rotating the device the code in `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation` is called and everything works perfectly.  (If I start the app in landscape orientation I can only scroll a little bit to see what is normally displayed in portrait mode and not the extended content - ignores the scrollView I've defined)

The code is the same in `viewDidAppear` and `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation` so why does the `scrollView` only respond after rotation?  Any help appreciated.

The output from the `NSLog` messages in both methods is the same.

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;


- (void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
   //If not an iPad set the scrollview to allow scrolling of view
   if (!([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)) {
      self.scrollView.contentSize= CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width,1000);
      [self.scrollView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
   }
   if(self.scrollView.userInteractionEnabled){
    NSLog(@"DEBUG scrollview height : %f",self.scrollView.contentSize.height);
    NSLog(@"DEBUG scrollview width : %f",self.scrollView.contentSize.width);    
   }
}

-(void) didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation{
//If not an iPad set the scrollview

    if (!([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)) {
        self.scrollView.contentSize= CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width,1000);
    }
    if(self.scrollView.userInteractionEnabled){
       NSLog(@"DEBUG scrollview height : %f",self.scrollView.contentSize.height);
       NSLog(@"DEBUG scrollview width : %f",self.scrollView.contentSize.width);
    }
}
```

Comment: You've forgotten to call `[super ...]` methods!

Comment: And you'd better change the `contentSize` in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`, which is called when appearing *and* when changing of orientation.

Comment: Thank you - the viewDidLayoutSubviews solved the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd better change the `contentSize` in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`, which is called when appearing *and* when changing the orientation.

But don’t forget to call `super` first!

Answer (score 1):

Hey Please Try this code I think your problem is solve using this code.

Try didRotate method in fetch your device orientation is Landscape or portrait. and set frame based on that.

```
 - (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {    
        if (!([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)) {
            self.scrollView.contentSize= CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width,1000);
            [self.scrollView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
        } else {
            [_scrollView setScrollEnabled:YES];
            _scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(_scrollView.frame.size.width, 2320);
        }
        if(self.scrollView.userInteractionEnabled){
            NSLog(@"DEBUG scrollview height : %f",self.scrollView.contentSize.height);
            NSLog(@"DEBUG scrollview width : %f",self.scrollView.contentSize.width);
        } }

    -(void) didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation
    {
        if (fromInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || fromInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
            [_scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(736, 1000)];

        } else {
            [_scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(414 , 1200)];

        }
    }
```

Happy Coding.

Comment: It is better to explain what is the change and why rather than giving just the code.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I will try my best next time.